# How can I obtain MySQL Connector Java Maven Dependency

Tags: java, mysql, database, intellij-idea, jdbc

I have downloaded MySQL Workbench for my database, and IntelliJ for the JDBC. However, while watching a tutorial, it was mentioned that I need the MySQL dependency in a pom.xml file. Any idea on how to obtain that?

Answer (score 9):

To connect to a MySQL database server from a Java app, you need a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver). The *MySQL Connector/J* product is one such JDBC driver.

You can obtain *MySQL Connector/J* via Maven. Look at a Maven repository for the `<dependency>` XML fragment. Copy-paste that within the `<dependencies>` tag of your POM file.

For example, look at [MvnRepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java).

As of 8.0.29:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.29</version>
</dependency>
```

Before version 8.0.29:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.24</version>
</dependency>
```

---

A [POM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) file is the place to configure a project whose build is driven by [*Apache Maven*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven). Maven is one of the most popular build tools. Another is [*Apache Gradle*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle), which provides dependency management via the same Maven repositories.

Comment: for versions above 8.0.29 use groupId `com.mysql` and artifactId `mysql-connector-j` as per documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the MySQL dependency in pom.xml files

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.24</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In any pom.xml files? Or specific ones? If specific ones, from where can I get them? And thank you for the reply :)

Comment: create pom.xml file in Project root folder and add it there 
example https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that:

1. Add the MySQL connector-j dependency in you `pom.xml`:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add your database URL and configuration in the `application.properties` file:

   ```
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database-name
   spring.datasource.username=database-User-name
   spring.datasource.password=your-database-password
   ```